# Split a list and duplicate values

Tags: list, split, ansible, duplicates

I'm trying to split a list and duplicate some values depending on the output but I'm unable to get it to work. I'm probably overthinking it but I've the below code where I'm storing the values in a list

```
  - set_fact:
      devices: "{{devices.list|json_query('[*].{serial: stacked_serial,
                                                IPv4: IPv4,
                                                version: version,
                                                hostname: Hostname,
                                                models: stacked_models}') }}"
```

Resulting in the below output

```
'}) => {
    "msg": {
        "IPv4": "1.2.3.4",
        "hostname": "name",
        "models": "model1,model2,model3",
        "serial": "serial1,serial2,serial3",
        "version": "1.1"
    }
}
```

What I want to achive is fairly simple, if 3 (this number can be different) serial numbers exist the serial should be split and the rest of the values duplicate. I want it to look like the below output (both the model and the serial should be split, model and serial will always match i.e if 3 serial exists 3 models will exist).

```
'}) => {
    "msg": {
        "IPv4": "1.2.3.4",
        "hostname": "name",
        "models": "model1",
        "serial": "serial1",
        "version": "1.1"
    }
}
'}) => {
    "msg": {
        "IPv4": "1.2.3.4",
        "hostname": "name",
        "models": "model2",
        "serial": "serial2",
        "version": "1.1"
    }
}

'}) => {
    "msg": {
        "IPv4": "1.2.3.4",
        "hostname": "name",
        "models": "model3",
        "serial": "serial3",
        "version": "1.1"
    }
}
```

The main goal with the above is to be able to run it through an API and later store it as a CSV file.

I've tried a few different scenarios and the below code is probably the closest. If someone could point me in the right direction I would be grateful. I know that I've solved this in python but that was a while back and I'm unable to translate it to ansible.

```
  - set_fact:
      testing: "{{testing|default([])}} + {{item.serial.split(',')}} + {{item.hostname}}"
    loop: "{{devices}}"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Took a step back and it was easy to solve it, kept overthinking it. Instead of reading the file as a list I just read the file as a dict and the solution kinda presented itself. Can obviously be done nicer but this works in my case.

```
  - name: Testing
    set_fact:
      _new_dict: "{{_new_dict|default([]) + [item|combine
                    ({'stacked_serial': item.stacked_serial[2],
                      'Hostname': item.Hostname,
                      'stacked_models_count': item.stacked_models_count})]}}"
    loop: "{{new_dict}}"
    when:
      - item.stacked_serial[2] is defined
```